# How do I adjust a container/boostrap grid to occupy whole screen?

Tags: image, grid, containers

I'm trying to use bootstrap grid to format my webpage layout. There are two elements on my page, an image and a subtitle for the image. I would like that both elements occupy the whole screen of a smartphone, just under the navbar. Could anyone help me? I'm also tryint to make it looks nice on pc and other plataforms.

I have done some progress using media screen, but its still clunky.

Thats my .index html:

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="combocontainer col-lg-12">

        <div class="combocontainer">

          <div class="top-container">
            <img class="avatar" src="Images/minimalist.jpg" alt="avatar" />
          </div>
          <div class="signature">
            <h1>My Name</h1>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Thats my css:

```css
.avatar {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 220px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


.combocontainer{
  height: 100vh;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .combocontainer {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 6rem;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 20%;
        width: 20%;
    }
}


/* No implementation yet */
.signature {
  text-align: center;
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
  font-family: "romatehood-p73ed-webfont";
}
```